# Infinite scrolling not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, lazy-loading, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement infinite scrolling function but it seems that my code is not working. Can you help me?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var origElement = $('.scroll').clone();

    if($(window).width() > 500){
        $('.scroll').jscroll();
        }

    $(window).resize(function(){
        if($(window).width() < 500){
            alert($(window).width());
           $('.scroll').remove();
           $('#container').append(origElement);
           }
        else{
             $('.scroll').jscroll();
            }
        });
});
```

Bellow is my html code:

```
    <div id="container">
    <div class="scroll">
        <h3>Page 1</h3>
        <p>Page 1 of jScroll Example - jQuery Infinite Scrolling Plugin

    This is the content of page 1 in the jScroll example. Scroll to the bottom of this box to load the next set of content.

    This is example text for the jScroll demonstration. jScroll is a jQuery plugin for infinite scrolling, endless scrolling, lazy loading, auto-paging, or whatever you may call it.

    With jScroll, you can initialize the scroller on an element with a fixed height and overflow setting of "auto" or "scroll," or it can be set on a standard block-level element within the document and the scrolling will be initialized based on the brower window's scroll position.

    jScroll is open-source and can be downloaded from my GitHub repository at github.com/pklauzinski/jscroll. </p>
        <a href="www.google.bg">next page</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thanks

I am trying to run the first example in JSFIDDLE but it seems it is not working: http://jscroll.com/

Comment: Am getting `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (NOT FOUND)` exception in the console for `example-page2.html`

Comment: @Guruprasad Rao I replaced the link with code. Thanks

Comment: Same erro with that code. `"NetworkError: 404 NOT FOUND - http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/www.google.bg"`

Comment: check for any console errors in your browser!! `fiddle` might not be allowing your external html to `load`